# I can understand this $B$ is symmetric. But I cannot understand why $B$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I am reading "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin.

---

> Suppose $A$ is a symmetric matrix with associated quadratic form $\mathcal{Q}$.

> Suppose $\mathcal{Q}$ is positive definite. Then, in particular, $\mathcal{Q}(\mathbf{e}_1)=a_{11}>0$, so we can write
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\
> \frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}\\
> \vdots\\
> \frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11}\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1&\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}&\cdots&\frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}
> \end{bmatrix}
> +\begin{bmatrix}
> 0&0&\cdots&0 \\
> 0&b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
> \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
> 0&b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
> \end{bmatrix},$$
> where $\begin{bmatrix}
> b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
> \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
> b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
> \end{bmatrix}$ is also symmetric and the quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ associated to $\begin{bmatrix}
> b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
> \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
> b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
> \end{bmatrix}$ is likewise positive definite.

---

I can understand $\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is also symmetric because both of $A$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}&\cdots&\frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}
\end{bmatrix}$ are symmetric.
But I cannot understand why $\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is also a positive definite matrix.

---

I verified the equality (Please see Professor Shifrin's answer below):

$a_{11}^2 B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}=\mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big)$

---

Let $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_{n-1}\\\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\\mathbf{x}\\\end{bmatrix}$.
$b_{ij}=a_{i+1\,j+1}-\frac{a_{i+1\,1}}{a_{11}}a_{1\,j+1}$ for $i,j$ such that $1\leq i\leq n-1,1\leq j\leq n-1$.

---

$$B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} b_{ii}x_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1} 2b_{ij}x_i x_j\\=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1\,i+1}-\frac{a_{1\,i+1}^2}{a_{11}})x_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1} 2(a_{i+1\,j+1}-\frac{a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1}}{a_{11}})x_i x_j.$$
$$a_{11}^2 B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,i+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}^2)x_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1} 2(a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,j+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1})x_i x_j.$$

The coefficient of $x_i^2$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,i+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}^2$.
The coefficient of $x_i x_j$ for each $i,j$ such that $1\leq i<j\leq n$ is $2(a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,j+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1})$.

---

$$a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\a_{11} x_1\\\vdots\\a_{11} x_{n-1}\\\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}a_{21}x_1+a_{31}x_2+\dots+a_{n1}x_{n-1}\\0\\\vdots\\0\\\end{bmatrix}\\=\begin{bmatrix}-(a_{21}x_1+a_{31}x_2+\dots+a_{n1}x_{n-1})\\a_{11} x_1\\\vdots\\a_{11} x_{n-1}\\\end{bmatrix}.$$
$$\mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big)=a_{11}(a_{21}x_1+a_{31}x_2+\dots+a_{n1}x_{n-1})^2+\sum_{i=2}^n a_{ii} (a_{11} x_{i-1})^2\\
+\sum_{2\leq j\leq n} 2 a_{1j}(-a_{21}x_1-a_{31}x_2-\dots-a_{n1}x_{n-1})(a_{11}x_{j-1})\\
+\sum_{2\leq i<j} 2 a_{ij} (a_{11}^2 x_{i-1} x_{j-1}).$$

The coefficient of $x_i^2$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $a_{11}a_{i+1\,1}^2+a_{i+1\,i+1}a_{11}^2+2a_{1\,i+1}(-a_{i+1\,1})a_{11}=a_{11}a_{1\,i+1}^2+a_{11}^2a_{i+1\,i+1}-2a_{11}a_{1\,i+1}^2=a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,i+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}^2.$
The coefficient of $x_i x_j$ for each $i,j$ such that $1\leq i<j\leq n$ is $a_{11}(2a_{i+1\,1}a_{j+1\,1})+2a_{1\,j+1}(-a_{i+1\,1})a_{11}+2a_{1\,i+1}(-a_{j+1\,1})a_{11}+2a_{i+1\,j+1}a_{11}^2=2a_{11}a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1}-2a_{11}a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1}-2a_{11}a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1}+2a_{11}^2a_{i+1\,j+1}= 2(a_{11}^2 a_{i+1\,j+1}-a_{11} a_{1\,i+1}a_{1\,j+1}).$

---

I verified the following equality without coordinates (Please see Professor Shifrin's comment below):

$a_{11}^2 B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}=\mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big)$

---

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}&\cdots&\frac{a_{1n}}{a_{11}}
\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\cdots&0 \\
0&b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
0&b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\=
\frac{1}{a_{11}}\mathbf{a_1}\mathbf{a_1}^T
+\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\cdots&0 \\
0&b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
0&b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
\overline{\mathbf{x}}^T A \overline{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{a_{11}}\overline{\mathbf{x}}^T\mathbf{a_1}\mathbf{a_1}^T\overline{\mathbf{x}}+\mathbf{x}^T B \mathbf{x}=\\
A\overline{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\overline{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{a_{11}}(\mathbf{a_1}\cdot\overline{\mathbf{x}})^2+B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}.
$$
$$
\mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big)=
a_{11}^2Q\big(\tilde{\mathbf x}\big)-2a_{11}(\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)A\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf e_1+
(\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)^2Q\big(\mathbf{e_1}\big)=\\
a_{11}^2Q\big(\tilde{\mathbf x}\big)-2a_{11}(\mathbf a_1\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x})(\mathbf a_1\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x})+
(\mathbf a_1\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x})^2a_{11}=\\
a_{11}^2Q\big(\tilde{\mathbf x}\big)-a_{11}(\mathbf a_1\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x})^2=
a_{11}^2 B\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}.
$$

Comment: He posts here so may have a specific proof in mind.  If you understand eigenvalue interlacing, then the result is immediate.  Another way would be via congruence.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @user8675309 if it's ok with you, do you mind posting the proof via congruence?

Comment: That's quite a tour de force of computation. With no coordinates, proceed as follows. If $\mathcal Q(\mathbf z) = A\mathbf z\cdot\mathbf z$, then you can check that $\mathcal Q(a\mathbf z + b\mathbf w) = a^2\mathcal Q(\mathbf z) + 2ab A\mathbf z\cdot\mathbf w + b^2\mathcal Q(\mathbf w)$. And $B\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf x = A\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x} - \dfrac1{a_{11}}(\vec a_1\cdot\tilde{\mathbf x})^2$.

Comment: @tchappyha I would encourage you to practice doing vector and matrix computations (like this) without resorting to individual coordinates.

Comment: @TedShifrin Professor Shifrin, Thank you very very much for your advice. With no coordinates, my calculation became much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask a good question. Because it was not central to the text, I provided only a "sketch of a proof," but you did omit the hint I gave that will answer your question. In the text, I suggested looking at
$\mathcal Q(a_{11}\mathbf e_2-a_{12}\mathbf e_1)$ to see why the first entry of $B$ must be positive. Indeed,
$$a_{11}^2 b_{11} = a_{11}(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2) = \mathcal Q(a_{11}\mathbf e_2-a_{12}\mathbf e_1)>0,$$
so $b_{11}>0$. You can generalize this immediately to get all the diagonal entries of $B$. And it gives the clue to the general situation.

Given $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$, let $\tilde{\mathbf x} = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ \mathbf x\end{matrix}\right]$. I will leave it to you to verify that
$$a_{11}^2 B\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf x = \mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big) > 0$$
whenever $\tilde{\mathbf x}\ne \mathbf 0$. Here $\mathbf a_1$, as usual in the text, is the first column vector of $A$.

The criterion for positive (negative) definiteness in terms of determinants of principal minors is not covered in this text, since it was intended to be primarily a multivariable analysis text. But the criterion in terms of positive (negative) eigenvalues is treated in the exercises in Section 4 of Chapter 9. Sylvester's law of inertia appears in the final exercise (and was also proved in the final lecture posted in my YouTube lectures).

Comment: Professor Shifrin, Thank you very very much for your answer. I verified the equality $a_{11}^2 B\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf x = \mathcal Q\big(a_{11}\tilde{\mathbf x} - (\tilde{\mathbf x}\cdot\mathbf a_1)\mathbf e_1\big)$.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite $A$ as
\begin{aligned}
A&=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\ a_{12}\\ \vdots\\ a_{1n}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{a_{11}}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\end{bmatrix}
+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 0&B\end{bmatrix}}_P
=\frac{Ae_1e_1^TA}{e_1^TAe_1}+P
\end{aligned}
where $e_1^T=(1,0,\ldots,0)$. If $Q$ is positive definite, $\langle u,v\rangle=u^TAv$ defines an inner product. Therefore, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{aligned}
x^TPx
=\frac{(x^TAx)(e_1^TAe_1)-(e_1^TAx)^2}{e_1^TAe_1}
=\frac{\langle x,x\rangle\langle e_1,e_1\rangle-\langle e_1,x\rangle^2}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}\ge0
\end{aligned}
and equality holds only when $x$ is parallel to $e_1$. In particular,  $x^TPx>0$ whenever $x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ y\end{bmatrix}\ne0$. That is, $y^TBy=x^TPx>0$ whenever $y\ne0$. Thus the quadratic form associated with $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: Interestingly, this seems identical in concept to my argument above.

Comment: @TedShifrin In a way, it is. I think it is less intimidating to present an inequality in the form of Cauchy-Schwarz, but this is certainly up to one's taste.

Comment: @user1551 really nice!.

Comment: user1551, Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very crude proof, using sub-additivity of rank.

$A=\mathbf {xx}^T + B' =\mathbf {xx}^T
+\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&\cdots&0 \\
0&b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1\,n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
0&b_{n-1\,1}&\cdots&b_{n-1\,n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
where  $A\succ \mathbf 0$

The claim is that $B'$ has signature $(n-1,0)$ and implicitly $\dim \ker B'=1$.

(In all cases I take for granted that $\mathbf e_1 \in \ker B'$)

**Case 1 (easy):** suppose $\text{rank}\big(B'\big)\leq n-2$, then
$n =\text{rank}\big(A\big)=\text{rank}\big(\mathbf {xx}^T + B'\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(\mathbf {xx}^T\big) + \text{rank}\big(B'\big)\leq 1 + n-2\lt n$
which is a contradiction.  This proves that $\text{rank}\big(B'\big) = n-1$.

**Case 2 (general):** suppose $B'$ has $k\geq 1$ negative eigenvalues and $\dim \ker B'=1$.
Then for appropriately selected eigenvectors
$B'':= B' +\sum_{i=1}^k \mathbf u_i\mathbf u_i^T \succeq 0$
and $\dim \ker B'' = k + 1 \gt 1$

But a PD matrix plus PSD matrices is PD so
$A': = \mathbf {xx}^T + B'' \succ \mathbf 0$ and as before
$n =\text{rank}\big(A'\big)=\text{rank}\big(\mathbf {xx}^T + B''\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(\mathbf {xx}^T\big) + \text{rank}\big(B''\big)\leq 1 + n-(k+1) \lt n$
which is again a contradiction.

hence $B'$ has exactly $n-1$ positive eigenvalues and one eigenvalue of zero.

Comment: user8675309, Thank you very much for your answer!